# jQuery UI Tabs run function when tabs is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs widget. How do we run a function when a tab is clicked on. I can't find any built in event that handles this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select):

> `tabsselect`
>   This event is triggered when clicking a tab.

```
// Supply a callback function to handle the select event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});

// Bind to the select event by type: tabsselect.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Note: if you want to run a function *after* the tab has loaded (especially if it's a remote tab), you probably want the `load`/`tabsload` event instead.

Comment: I tried this solution, and i thought i was doing something wrong, but  seems like something else in code causing the function not to run. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Are you using the browser dev tools (F12 in IE, c-s-I in Chrome, Firebug in Firefox)? They're awesome for things like this

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation from jquery UI

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

[Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select)

Comment: I can't find anything explaining any of the events triggered within UI-tabs in its docs.